# Does my ε-NFA not contain the right number of transitions?

Tags: computer-science, computation-theory, finite-automata

[image: my attempt]

The question: Construct a ε-NFA that accepts all strings starting and ending with different symbols. I have shown my teacher my answer, and she said there's a small mistake in it. But I can't find what's wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the string `"a"`.
You could go to state `A`, then `B`, then (with empty string) to `C` and accept the string. Yet `"a"` does not start and end with different symbols.

I think you can simplify your design a bit, but you seem to be on the right track.

Comment: Does it matter if the ε-NFA rejects or accepts invalid strings as long as it accepts the valid ones? We weren't taught as such so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: @SandyKetchum Well ok, I suppose technically the problem definition only asked to accept all those and not to reject all others :) But then you could just accept every string in the world and be done with it. I assumed here the somewhat more useful problem definition of "accept a string if and only if it starts and ends with a different symbol".

Comment: @SandyKetchum ...and based on your teacher's feedback, I suspect this is what she was after :)

Comment: That way of seeing the question makes a lot more sense. I'll take another crack at the problem with this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I find it particularly easy to convert regular expressions to NFAs.  In this case you're looking for the union of `a(a|b)*b` and `b(a|b)*a`.  Each of those can be easily converted into a NFA with no ε transitions.